# Will semaphore mechanism cause deadlock?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock, semaphore

As semaphore mechanism uses two queues:

- Block queue
- Ready queue

In two possible cases:

If ①the signal of semaphore is negative (considerably large),

②an essential process which provides required resources is blocked, will there be deadlock?

---

For example, we have three processes in block queue but the signal is negative five (s = -5), will the processes forever blocked in the queue?

In the second case, if process P1, P2, P3 relies on results of P4, and P4 is blocked in a queue (is it possible?), so is there nothing we can do to increase semaphore by semSignal(), indicating a deadlock?

Comment: 'the signal of semaphore is negative' - how can that happen?  Semaphore counts are positive integers or zero.  I don't understand - some implementation detail?  Negative integers index the wait queue?

Comment: @MartinJames when semaphore is negative, the mechanism blocks related processes. As if it's -5, it will block 5 processes in a "block queue"; processes will not be put into the "ready queue" until semaphore is set up to positive. Each semWait() minus 1 from semaphore, and semSignal() increases it by 1.

Comment: And I got this from William Stallings' book "Operating Systems", there's no implementation detail. I checked it multiple times and I thought I didn't got the concept much wrong.

Comment: You misunderstood the book or the book is wrong.  If five threads are waiting on a semaphore, it is because the semaphore count is zero.  If the semaphore is signaled at this time, one of the waiting threads will become ready and the count will remain at zero.  There is no scenario where there are waiting threads and one signal does not make one of them ready.  If there is some synchro primitive/object that behaves as you describe, it is not a semaphore.

Comment: I may accept that an integer count that may be negative is one way of conceptualising and/or implementing a count.  The condition for a waiting thread to be released upon a signal would be 'count<0 before increment' however, not 'count>0 after increment'.

Comment: @MartinJames The book described two scenarios of semaphore: `<0`, `>=0`. Negative semaphore keeps blocking processes to be ready. If semaphore is set -1, block one process; -2 blocks two. When semaphore is signaled `>=0`, it allows processes ready and count down to 0. Each ready manipulation minus 1 from the semaphore, until processes blocked again. In your description the idea is the same, just differ in trivial implementation.

Comment: @MartinJames And I think if an essential process (provides necessary resource) is blocked and unfortunately at the time semaphore happens to be negative, it could trigger a deadlock. If I didn't misunderstand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, we have three processes in block queue but the signal is
>   negative five (s = -5), will the processes forever blocked in the
>   queue?

If you accept the concept of semaphore counts becoming negative, ie. negative values represent the number of waiting threads, the count could not become -5 if there are only three threads waiting.  If that happens, your semaphore implementation is borked.

> In the second case, if process P1, P2, P3 relies on results of P4, and
>   P4 is blocked in a queue (is it possible?), so is there nothing we can
>   do to increase semaphore by semSignal(), indicating a deadlock?

I do not understand this scenario. It does not describe a deadlock.  If P4 is stuck on some queue, and that is the reason why the four thread cannot make forward progress because they are all blocked, then you should work out why P4 got stuck in the first place.

A deadlock might occur if P4 is waiting for some signal from p1, p2 and/or p3.

Shoving in extra semaphore units to attempt to escape a deadlock would be, in all the cases I can think of, a band-aid on a leaking nuclear reactor.